# LowMemory Access Crash Report in ARC based Project of iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

i got some critical issue of memory warning in ipad.

My project is ARC based. and its simple UIKit base game.

here i have attached one screenshot of the error log which generate in 
Setting -> General -> About -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostics & Usage Data

[image]

And my ipad detail over here.
Hardware Model : iPad 1
OS version : iPhone OS 5.0.1

And my ipad project is almost around 120 MB source file (i mean size of IPA which create from this project.).
And it works fine in Simulator. but not in ipad.

Whats exactly problem which i couldn't able to found over here.. ?

Please let me know if any one have help ful input for this query.

Regards,

Comment: did you run instruments? What else have you tried?

Comment: does this app work perfectly on higher versions of iPad(iPad2, new iPad). Have you tried analyzing the memory leaks in your code, use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211158/memory-leak-when-using-cgimagecreatewithjpegdataprovider/12211965#comment16408104_12211965)

Comment: Go to iTunes, iTunes U, download 2012 WWDC videos and check sessions about memory management, profiling, how to use instruments to find memory leaks, ... Really useful stuff ...

Comment: if its ARC base than still wants to check memory management !!

Answer (score 1):

Using ARC in your project doesn't solve all possible memory issues automatically. You are most likely still having memory leaks OR you are allocating too much memory and trying to keep too much memory allocated. You should use instruments to check the memory usage and search for these two issues.

If you don't know how to use instruments, this stackoverflow answer highlights some of the relevant WWDC videos: [Understanding Instruments in Xcode, testing for leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248345/understanding-instruments-in-xcode-testing-for-leaks/8248424#8248424)

Comment: i have check with Instruments and still its up to show 3 - 4 MB live bytes while performing to play game. Can you explain me about live bytes and overall bytes.. ? B'coz i found some links which explain it but i could not get it whats exact.. please post your helpful comments..